# Are pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX getting (much) slower in macOS?

Tags: xetex, pdftex, luatex, texlive, compiling

**SOLVED: see bottom of message!**

I sensed pdfLaTeX was slower in TeX-Live 2020 and decided to run some benchmarking…

- Computer: MacBook Pro (2018) with SSD
- Document: The ["novathesis" thesis template](https://github.com/joaomlourenco/novathesis)
- LaTeX Version(s): MacTex 2019, 2020, 2021 (all versions up to date)

The chart shows the execution time (as the average of 5 consecutive runs) for pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX, versions 2019, 2020 and 2021.

[image: tex-live execution times per release]

My reading of the charts is:

1. pdfLaTeX and XeLaTeX go side-by-side on execution times (XeLaTeX is becoming slightly faster);
2. pdfLaTeX and XeLaTeX are getting slower with each release (with a huge slowdown for 2020);
3. The slowdown in LuaLaTeX is less noticeable and in macTeX 2020 LuaLaTeX is competing with pdfLaTeX and XeLaTeX (by demerit of pdfLaTeX and XeLaTeX that became much slower).

Questions:

1. Do you have a similar experience?
2. What happened to pdfLaTeX and XeLaTeX to suffer such a slowdown?

**UPDATE**

Another benchmarking, now with (almost) no additional packages. Used the average of 5 runs, in same computer, with the code below (BTW, the resulting PDF is 545 pages):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \newcounter{int}
    \setcounter{int}{1}
    \loop
        \lipsum[1-30]
        \addtocounter{int}{1}
        \ifnum \value{int}<100
    \repeat
\end{document}
```

Execution times below:

[image]

My reading from the numbers above is that *the pdf/Xe/Lua-LaTeX engines are not getting slower*.  But as a user, I'm experiencing a considerable slowdown overall…  Can it really be from `kpsewhich`?  How to measure/evaluate that?

Comment: There was no significant changes to the engines (that I recall) that would justify that.  I would guess, if your benchmarking is correct, that the number of existing packages in the distribution may influence the time `kpsewhich` takes to search your TeX tree.  One way to test that would be to benchmark a document with fewer packages and see if the time difference gets smaller

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Could it be the compression method used for the format file? That was changed as the files were getting a bit big.

Comment: @Phelype Oleinik, I counted the number of files in each release: 2019=199351; 2020=207000, 2021=207649.  The number of files in 2020 and 2021 is almost the same, which probably invalidates your guess.

Comment: @JosephWright Ah, maybe. Though that change was already in TL'20, I think...

Comment: on windows texlive 2021 is faster. For your template I get 28 seconds compared to 35 with texlive 2020 (only the pdflatex run).

Comment: Where are the error bars? Or did you only take a single measurement?

Comment: On my Linux box, using TL21 I get (average on 3 compilations each) using the OPs example with `\hfuzz=5pt`: 11.71s, 12.12s and 16.42s (pdflatex, xelatex and lualatex). Probably better to run each compilation 100 times and take the average on that.

Comment: There are tools for benchmarking command line programs, e.g. [bench](https://github.com/Gabriel439/bench) and [hyperfine](https://github.com/sharkdp/hyperfine). (Both available in homebrew: [bench](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/bench), [hyperfine](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/hyperfine)) Why not use that to benchmark `kpsewhich tikz.sty` or so? Output of `bench` for that: http://dpaste.com/2EN4H5LX5 (expires in 10 days)

Comment: I think may TL20 is about 1.5 sec faster on each engine. For TL19 pdflatex and xelatex is more or less the same as TL20, whereas lualatex is again another 1.5s faster. But still the slowest

Comment: are you sure your tl2021 environment is correct and that you are using cached ls-lr files and not searching the filesystem?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I just installed the macTeX-2021 package, as I did with all the previous releases of TL.  And the behavior is consistent (repeatable) if I switch between TL releases. Could it be something with the macTeX-2021 installation package? If I rename the 3 "ls-R" files to something else pdf/xe/lua-latex terminate with error messages, so I guess I'm using the "ls-R" files..

Comment: using the lipsum loop you show here tl2021 pdflatex is consistently faster than tl2020 pdflatex  with 2021 giving typical values after a couple of runs 0f real    0m11.201s user    0m11.078s sys     0m0.109s  and tl2020 giving real    0m12.401s user    0m12.328s sys     0m0.077s

Comment: compare logs with `pdflatex -kpathsea-debug=1 `  (or -1 if you are feeling brave)  so it logs all the filesystem activity

Comment: Just noticed that macTeX 2021 comes with “universal binaries” (x86 and ARM).  Could this be a macOS specific problem related with the universal binaries?

Comment: I don't have a mac so can not test that, sorry

Comment: An additional insight…

`latexmk -pdf template` (see initial post for info on the source file) with:
TeX-Live 2019:    `real 0m21.858s  user 0m18.981s  sys 0m1.803s`
TeX-Live 2021:   `real 1m2.803s  user 0m34.444s  sys 0m25.244s`

In TL2021 the user time is slightly higher (can it be because of the universal binaries)?  But the system time is **so much** higher!!

Comment: Maybe you can use `unravel` https://ctan.org/pkg/unravel?lang=en to test if the kernel update is to blame?

Comment: @JoãoLourenço Could you please run `latex '\stop'` on each case and show me what version of LaTeX2e and L3 programming layer you are running on?

Comment: You can find the output [here in pastebin](https://pastebin.com/AhMtgxrt). The link is valid for 2 weeks.  Let me know if I can help in debugging this problem.

Comment: @JoãoLourenço Sorry, my question was unclear: I meant I want to see the output of `latex '\stop'` with TeX Live 2019, 2020, and 2021, so that I can see which version of LaTeX you are running on each system (currently the version of LaTeX on TL 2020 and TL 2021 should be the same, so that would give us a clue).  We are investigating the source of this slowdown, but it varies a lot from one system to another, so we have very few clues so far

Comment: Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019) • LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5 • L3 programming layer <2020-02-25> / Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) • LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4 • L3 programming layer <2021-02-18> / Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2021) • LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4 • L3 programming layer <2021-02-18>

Comment: @JoãoLourenço Many thanks!

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik, if you need/want, please contact me at joao.lourenco (at) fct.unl.pt

Comment: @JoãoLourenço Thanks, address noted.  We are currently investigating the issue which seems all very odd.  For example you have the same version of LaTeX on TL'20 and 21, which means (in principle) it's not due to a change in LaTeX (we did have a huge change in LaTeX from the 2020-02-02 version to 2020-10-01, which could explain the difference you see between 2019 and 2020).  On the other hand, I couldn't spot changes in the engines that would justify this, so the problem doesn't seem to be there either.  It's all _very_ strange...

Comment: could you benchmark the file access on your system? E.g with `\usepackage{l3benchmark}\ExplSyntaxOn
\benchmark:n{\file_get_full_name:nN{article.cls}\l_tmpa_tl}
\ExplSyntaxOff` with a variety of files (from different texmf, in the current folder, without extension). benchmark reports the values in the log.

Comment: I get between 700 and 850 ops in all the versions (2019, 2020 and 2021), depending on the attempt, and also on the file (for example, with `article.cls` I get slightly more ops than with `memoir.cls`).  I did not find  a trend in any of the versions.

Comment: Tex-Live 2020 — the sum or the partial times is almost the total time
`'pdflatex  -interaction=batchmode -recorder  "template.tex"': time = 5.1
'biber --onlylog  "template.bcf"': time = 2.03
'pdflatex  -interaction=batchmode -recorder  "template.tex"': time = 5.5
'biber --onlylog  "template.bcf"': time = 1.95
'pdflatex  -interaction=batchmode -recorder  "template.tex"': time = 5.62
'pdflatex  -interaction=batchmode -recorder  "template.tex"': time = 5.48
Accumulated processing time = 27.13`

Comment: Tex-Live 2021 — the sum or the partial times is the same as above, but the total time is +60 seconds
`'pdflatex  -interaction=batchmode -recorder  "template.tex"': time = 4.91
'biber --onlylog  "template.bcf"': time = 1.92
'pdflatex  -interaction=batchmode -recorder  "template.tex"': time = 5.32
'biber --onlylog  "template.bcf"': time = 1.93
'pdflatex  -interaction=batchmode -recorder  "template.tex"': time = 5.32
'pdflatex  -interaction=batchmode -recorder  "template.tex"': time = 5.33
Accumulated processing time = 61.56`
 A friend using macOS Catalina does not observe this problem.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik, I deleted TL2021 and reinstalled.  It is fast!  Faster than TL2020. :)     Then I apply the pending updates and it gets slllooowww.  Not sure yet which update causes the slowdown, but we're getting there.

Comment: @JoãoLourenço Wow, really? That's surprising, because the main suspect, LaTeX itself, didn't change _at all_ since the beginning of TL21.  If you are updating with `tlmgr` you can do `tlmgr update <package>` and try one by one (which can be a huge pain depending on the list of packages).  That said, we do have some speed improvements regarding file loading that should be released next week or so, so you may see some improvement (but nothing miraculous, be warned).  Thanks for the update, and if you find out anything else about this, please let me know! :)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik, the problem was in `latexmk 58886 (4.72b)`, which when applied made the compiling time of my document increase from 32 to 76 seconds. 
The current update of `latexmk 59081 (4.73)` solves the issue. 

Comment: There was also a considerable slowdown after updating the package `erewhon` (_not used in my document_), which increased the compiling time consistently from 27 to 32 sec.

Comment: @JoãoLourenço Please post a self-answer and once done remove the answer part from the question: that's the structure the site uses

Comment: @JoãoLourenço Ah, so you used `latexmk`!  Just yesterday I was looking at the changelog entry for the latest update:  “Revert the change of 14-15 Apr, by removing the of `cwd()`.  That gave sometimes obnoxiously slow parsing of big log files, because of the slowness of large number of calls to `cwd()` caused by calls to sub `normalize_filename`.”  Nice find! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was in latexmk 58886 (4.72b), which when applied made the compiling time of my document increase from 32 to 76 seconds. The current update of latexmk 59081 (4.73) solves the issue.

The reason for the slowdown (and the fix) is in the changelog entry for [version 4.73](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Build/source/texk/texlive/linked_scripts/latexmk/latexmk.pl?r1=59081&r2=59080&pathrev=59081):

```perl
## 30 Apr 2021 John Collins  Revert the change of 14-15 Apr, by removing the
##                           of cwd().  That gave sometimes obnoxiously slow
##                           parsing of big log files, because of the slowness
##                           of large number of calls to cwd() caused by calls
##                           to sub normalize_filename. I think I am mistaken
##                           that cwd() could possibly give a different result
##                           than getcwd(), whose cached result is used by
##                           my goodcwd(). That idea was my motivation on 14 Apr.
```

Comment: Oh wow, you did not mention latexmk in the original question *at all*. How was anyone supposed to guess that?

Comment: @HenriMenke, you're right! Shame on me!